# Android Back button closes app for some reason

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

My app closes when I press the android back button but returns to the back page from the default back button from the app bar. I think the problem is due to providing bloc in navigation
I have navigated like this

```
   IconButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).push(
              CreateProfileFormPage.route(
                onFormSubmitSuccess: (context) {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
              ),
            );
          },
          icon: const Icon(FlatIcons.add),
        ),
```

Comment: on which screen you are facing this issues? any screen or on First Screen?

Answer (score 0):

you need to do is first clear all path before going to screen.

```
onPressed:(){
        clearSession();

      //Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName('/'));
      Navigator.pop(context,true);// It worked for me instead of above line
      Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Login()),);

},
```

Comment: I don't think it's from path i cleared but it's not working

Answer (score 0):

Removing the following line from the manifest helped me:

```
android:enableOnBackInvokedCallback="true"
```